# Equivalence induced matrix norms!

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

The equivalence of vector norms on finite dimensional spaces immediately implies that all induced matrix norms are equivalent. Theorem 1, [here](http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~andrew/notes/pdf/2010a.pdf), gives some of the popular induced norms. I am interested in the $\|A\|_{2,1}$ and $\|A\|_{2,2}$ norm, where
\begin{equation*}
\|A\|_{2,1}=\sup\{\|A\mathbf{x}\|_1:\|\mathbf{x}\|_2=1\}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\|A\|_{2,2}=\sup\{\|A\mathbf{x}\|_2:\|\mathbf{x}\|_2=1\}
\end{equation*}

According to my analysis so far; $\|A\|_{2,1}$ upper-bounds $\|A\|_{2,2}$. Can someone verify?

For a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$

$\|A\|_{2,1}=\max_{u\in\{1,-1\}^n}\|A^Tu\|_2\leq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^m(\sum_{j=1}^n|a_{ij}|)^2}$.

And 
$\|A\|_{2,2}=\lambda_{\max}(A^TA)=\sigma_{\max}(A)\leq\|A\|_F= \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n|a_{ij}|^2}$,

$\implies$
\begin{equation}
\|A\|_{2,2}^2\leq{\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n|a_{ij}|^2}\leq{\sum_{i=1}^m\left(\sum_{j=1}^n|a_{ij}|\right)^2}
\end{equation}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inequalities all go in the same direction, so you cannot possibly prove inequalities both ways.

You have the easy inequalities $$\|x\|_2\leq\|x\|_1\leq\sqrt n\,\|x\|_2.$$ So you immediately get (from the definition, not the characterization you quote)
$$\tag{1}\bbox[5px,border:2px solid green]{\|A\|_{2,2}\leq\|A\|_{2,1}\leq\sqrt n\|A\|_{2,2}.}
$$
These inequalities are sharp. For instance, if $A=E_{11}$, then 
$$
\|Ax\|_1=\|(x_1,0,\ldots,0)\|_1=|x_1|=\|x\|_2.
$$
So $\|A\|_{2,2}=\|A\|_{1,1}$. And if $A=I_m$, then $\|Ax\|_1=\|x\|_1$, so
$$
\|A\|_{2,1}=\max\{\|x\|_1:\ \|x\|_2=1\}=\sqrt n,
$$
while $\|A\|_{2,2}=1$. So $\|A\|_{2,1}=\sqrt n\|A\|_{2,2}$.

**Edit:** here is a short proof of the inequalities $(1)$, in case they are not obvious.

You have, for any nonzero $x$. 
$$
\frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\|x\|_2}\leq\frac{\|Ax\|_1}{\|x\|_2}\leq\|A\|_{2,1}.
$$
Now you take supremum (forget about the term on the middle) and you obtain
$$
\|A\|_{2,2}\leq\|A\|_{1,1}.
$$
Similarly, start with 
$$
\frac{\|Ax\|_1}{\|x\|_2}\leq\sqrt{n}\,\frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\|x\|_2}\leq\sqrt{n}\,\|A\|_{2,2}.
$$
Now forget the middle term and take supremum, to obtain
$$
\|A\|_{2,1}\leq\sqrt{n}\,\|A\|_{2,2}.
$$

Comment: what do you mean by characterization?

Comment: The definition is \begin{equation*}
\|A\|_{2,1}=\sup\{\|A\mathbf{x}\|_1:\|\mathbf{x}\|_2=1\}.
\end{equation*} You also have the characterization $$\|A\|_{2,1}=\max_{u\in\{1,-1\}^n}\|A^Tu\|_2.$$

Comment: Regarding your answer, we have to take supremum over $\|A\mathbf{x}\|$ such that $\|\mathbf{x}\|_2=1$, but there could be alot of $\mathbf{x}$ with unit $\ell_2$ norm and some $\mathbf{x}$ that maximizes $\|A\mathbf{x}\|_{2}$ might not maximize $\|A\mathbf{x}\|_{1}$.

Comment: Not sure how you think that affects my answer.

Comment: Let $\mathbf{x}'$ and $\mathbf{x}''$ be such that $\|.\|_2=1$ for both of them. Now, let $\sup\|A\mathbf{x}\|_1=\|A\mathbf{x}'\|_1$ and $\sup\|A\mathbf{x}\|_2=\|A\mathbf{x}''\|_2$, then your inequalities might not hold!

Comment: Why? $\ \ \ \ \ \ \  $

Comment: Ok, now I see what you don't understand. Give me a second.

Comment: Because these inequalities on norms hold for the same arguement i.e, $\ell_2$ norm of a vector is less than $\ell_1$ norm. We can't say $\|\mathbf{a}\|_2\leq\|\mathbf{b}\|_1$ for all $\mathbf{a,b}$.

Comment: You are kind of missing the point on how you play with the definition of a norm. You have, for any nonzero $x$. 
$$
\frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\|x\|_2}\leq\frac{\|Ax\|_1}{\|x\|_2}\leq\|A\|_{2,1}.
$$
Now you take supremum (forget about the term on the middle) and you obtain
$$
\|A\|_{2,2}\leq\|A\|_{1,1}.
$$
Similarly, start with 
$$
\frac{\|Ax\|_1}{\|x\|_2}\leq\sqrt{n}\,\frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\|x\|_2}\leq\sqrt{n}\,\|A\|_{2,2}.
$$
Now forget the middle term and take supremum, to obtain
$$
\|A\|_{2,1}\leq\sqrt{n}\,\|A\|_{2,2}.
$$

Comment: If it's not clear to you, someone else will get confused. So I'll edit this into the answer.